# Вопрос о запятых в двух предложениях

Tags: запятые

Уважаемые участники форума!

1. Скажите, пожалуйста, ставится ли запятая после сравнительного оборота в предложении:

Первый, избранный волей прямого Завета, как всадник(,) с небес сошёл.

Я изначально запятую поставила, но редактор убрал почему-то.

2. В предложении было вводное слово "в оправе":

Я явился в непамятный день, в ранний утренний час, где немая, в оправе(,) тоска лесов одевалась пред стражем теней в столь неброский, прохладный, как ситец, листвы наряд.

Редактор тоже почему-то убрал запятую. Верно ли?

Comment: Лана, мне не очень понятен смысл и грамматика второго предложения. Автор имеет право на любые художественные образы, но грамматика здесь неясная.  Я правильно понимаю? Немая тоска в оправе лесов одевалась в наряд листвы. Или что-то не так? Тогда поправьте. И тогда можно будет скорректировать художественную форму.

Comment: Здесь просто не совсем удачный художественный образ: "тоска лесов" - "немая" и "в оправе" (просто "в оправе" без дополнений).

Comment: Теперь грамматика правильная, это обособленное несогласованное определение. Но расскажите  тогда про смысл этого слова, иначе окончательно трудно сделать вывод.

Comment: А разве в поэзии художественный образ должен иметь чёткий прямолинейный смысл? Он ведь может быть и абстрактным. Это предложение взято из стихотворения, написанного в эпическом жанре. Мне просто очень нужно узнать, нужна ли там запятая, в том месте, где мной отмечено.

Comment: Смысл или символ - что-нибудь  из этого читатель должен выбрать. Из словаря:  ОПРАВА, -ы; ж. 1. То, во что вставляется, вделывается что-л.; что служит рамкой. О. бриллианта. Золочёная о. О. зеркала. 3. (чего, какой). О том, что окружает что-л.; обрамление. Снеговая о. вершин.

Comment: Да, смысл здесь именно "в обрамлении".

Comment: Но тогда возникает вопрос: в обрамлении чего? в какой оправе? что имеется в виду? Это читатель непременно захочет понять.

Comment: В моих стихах много недоговорённостей и "опущенных" (намеренно пропущенных для домысла) слов. Много абстракции. Поэзия бывает разной, в ней такое допустимо. Это не проза. В данном предложении "тоска лесов" просто "в обрамлении" (без ничего).

Comment: Тогда запятая нужна. Вы же обособляете это слово, выделяете его голосом?

Comment: Да, я как вводное слово его выделила с двух сторон запятыми, но редактор почему-то 2-ю убрал. Вот и задала вопрос на форуме, чтобы наверняка знать, как правильно.

Comment: Грамматика правильная,  без запятой никак не получится. Заходите, всегда рады вам помочь.

Comment: Благодарю Вас. А без второй запятой - сильно явная ошибка будет? Или возможны всё-таки оба варианта (с запятой и без неё)?

Comment: Боюсь, смысл будет совсем неясен. Я бы там даже интонационное тире поставила. В то же время  я не могу исключить какое-то особое понимание текста, но без запятой его просто не вижу.  Может быть, подождем другие ответы? Вдруг появится иное прочтение - без запятой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вторая часть  ответа

**Вопрос:** В предложении было вводное слово "в оправе":  *Я явился в непамятный день, в ранний утренний час, где **немая, в оправе(,) тоска лесов** одевалась пред стражем теней в столь неброский, прохладный, как ситец, листвы наряд.*
Редактор тоже почему-то убрал запятую. Верно ли?

1. Рассмотрим вариант **однородных определений**  (одна запятая) в сочетании: ***немАя, в оправе** тоска лесОв.*

Признаки перечисляются, они равноправны по значению.

2. Рассмотрим **обособленный  вариант** (две запятые): ***немАя, в опрАве**, тоска лесОв.*

Второй признак выделяется вставочной интонацией, при этом его значимость как художественной детали подчеркивается.

3. Проверяем **корректность грамматики первого варианта**: два определения, одно их которых несогласованное. Этот вариант рассмотрен в ПАС: (у Розенталя его нет) http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114

*§ 39. Запятая ставится при сочетании **согласованных и несогласованных** определений (несогласованное определение помещается **после согласованного**):
Между тем в **приземистой, с коричневыми стенами** зимовке Клюшиных действительно горела слегка увернутая семилинейная лампа (Бел.); Она сняла со стола **толстую, с бахромой скатерть** и постелила другую, белую (П. Нил.).*

Это действительно наш случай.

4. Итак, грамматика **корректна в обоих случаях,** но семантические и интонационные оттенки разные – это однородное перечисление  признаков  или интонационно выделенный второй признак как особо значимая художественная деталь.

Теперь (по большому счету) **выбор за автором**, а не за редактором.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое.

Answer (score 2):

Предложение 1

*Первый, избранный волей прямого Завета, как всАдник с небес сошёл.*

Здесь ***как всадник*** - сравнительный оборот в роли необособленного обстоятельства, на него падает **ударение** (= всадником сошел).

Comment: То есть запятая точно не нужна?

Comment: Да, точно не нужна.  Иначе у нас получатся два определения, следующих один за другим,  их даже не прочитаешь правильно.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!

Answer (score 1):

Редактор прав: в сравнительном обороте запятой между сказуемом и подлежащим быть не должно.

Во втором предложении следует разобраться с ***оправой***: оправой какой? оправой чего? оправой чему? Это место — *немая в оправе... тоска лесов одевалась* — не столько знаков препинания требует, сколько слов.

> ... дождик шуршащий в травах
>
> и дерево и стена
>
> телесная их оправа
>
> больной душе не нужна...

(*А. Пермяков «Никто не знает»*)

Вторая часть фразы (*неброский, прохладный, как ситец, листвы наряд*) нуждается в правке: вызывает вопрос её окончание — ***листвы наряд*** и сравнение ***прохладный, как ситец***, хотя возможно, это просто опечатка. Предлагаю переместить запятую: *неброский, прохладный, как ситец листвы, наряд*.

А вообще, — известные затруднения форматирования стиха имеются, — всё-таки не дурно было бы показать его скан/скрин. Правила сайта не приветствуют, но не запрещают.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. Во втором предложении имеется в виду, что "немая тоска" - просто "в оправе". Возможно, такой художественный образ не очень удачен. И "наряд листвы" был "прохладный, как ситец".

Comment: Такой порядок слов не характерен для прозы. Так «тоска лесов» — тоже не в том порядке? В оправе лесов тоска?

Comment: Это не проза. Предложения взяты из стихов. Если изменить порядок слов - придётся менять другие строки тоже, рифма изменится.

Comment: Припоминаю, Вы сюда уже заходили как-то.

Comment: Верно, заходила. Вопрос тоже о пунктуации был.

Answer (score 1):

Первая запятая не нужна точно, а вторая — в какой-то степени факультативна. Редактор, видимо, усмотрел здесь однородные члены предложения — определения «тоски лесов»: 1) немая; 2) в оправе.

> **§ 9. Однородные члены предложения, не соединенные союзами**
>
> 1. Между однородными членами предложения, связанными только интонационно, обычно ставится запятая: *Вопросы, восклицания, рассказы
>    посыпались наперерыв* (Тургенев.)
>
> http://www.old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=97#pp97

Видите? **Между** — запятые ставятся, а **после последнего** однородного члена — нет.

Но вы, видимо, предпочитаете, чтобы «в оправе» рассматривалось как присоединительный член предложения. И вы имеете на это полное право.

> **§ 24. Присоединительные конструкции**
>
> 1. Присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в середину либо в
>    конец высказывания, выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми (реже
>    используются тире, точка, многоточие).
>
> (...)
>
> 6. Присоединительные конструкции могут включаться в высказывание без союзов:
>    *Довольно поздно явился ещё гость, **во фраке*** (Герцен.)
>
> http://www.old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

Здесь присоединительный член предложения **отделяется** запятой, только с одной стороны, поскольку стоит в конце предложения. А вот он в середине (по той же ссылке):

> *Когда Филипп вышел на кухню, **умываться,** Анфиса Петровна спросила...* (Федин.)

Я думаю, вам следует объяснить редактору свою позицию и настаивать на ней.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, Егор.